# How to find out the index of td in next row in same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page. It contains table. I want to find out a particular cell's index  which is in the same position. ie,
Here is my table,

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Label 1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Label 2</td>
      <td colspan="2">Label 3</td>
      <td>Something else</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td> 2</td>
      <td> 3</td>
      <td> 4</td>
      <td> 5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here I want to find the index of the next row's td in the same position of item2.(ie, index of 4) .
How it is possible with jQuery?

Comment: @Alexander : Actually I want, when I click `<td>item2</td>` it shows the index of `<td> 4</td>`

Comment: Can you be more specific!! _next row's td in the same position of item2_ will be `2`  right?

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao : Nop. if click item 2 , i want to alert  index of`<td>4</td>`

Comment: ... because of the rowspan used in the first row

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Code snippets:** (updated)

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
var ele = $('table tr:eq(1)'), childEle = ele.children() ;
var len = childEle.length;    
for(var i=0; i< len;i++){
    var tdText = childEle.eq(i).text();
    var itemIndex = ele.children('td:contains("'+tdText+'")').index();
    var positionFromLast = len-(itemIndex);
    var nxtTrEle = ele.next();
    var nxtTrLength = nxtTrEle.children().length;
    var ind = nxtTrLength - positionFromLast;
    var reqIndex = nxtTrEle.children(':eq('+ind+')').index();
   alert(reqIndex);    
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Label 1</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Label 2</td>
      <td colspan="2">Label 3</td>
      <td>Something else</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Item 1</td>    
      <td>Item 2</td>
      <td>Item 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 1</td>
      <td> 2</td>
      <td> 3</td>
      <td> 4</td>
      <td> 5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<button>Get Parallel Index</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your code works fine for just one td. But If I want all td's index in the same way, how the code looks like?

Comment: Just change the value of `contains` by looping